# C# .NET scope is causing me to be unable to call both a method and a picturebox reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to follow a book on learning C# and I've run into a stumbling block.
We're supposed to build an app that has 4 dogs running across the screen, a race track simiulator.  I've got most of it working, save for the mechanism that moves the dogs across the track.
So, first I have the Greyhound class declared in another class file:

```
public class Greyhound
{
    public int StartingPosition;
    public int RaceTrackLength;
    public PictureBox MyPictureBox = null;
    public int Location = 0;
    public int Lane = 0;
    public Random Randomizer;


    public void Run() //Makes the dog move down the track.
    {
        Location += Randomizer.Next(0, 4);
        MyPictureBox.Location = new Point(Location, Lane);
    }
}
```

Then, in my form1.cs I have these two bits to initialize the objects:

```
 public void LoadDogs()
    {
        Greyhound Dog1 = new Greyhound()
        {
            StartingPosition = 30,
            MyPictureBox = pictureBox2, //Pointer at the picture box for this dog.
            Location = 30,  //X cordinates of the picture box
            Lane = 21 //Y cordinates of the picutre box
        };
    }


     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDogs();
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is I can't make Dog1.Run() actually work without breaking the initialization of the Object.

If I try and put Dog1.Run() inside of a timer1_Tick event, it complains "The name 'Dog1' does not exist in the current context."

I can correct this if I put the instantiation "Greyhound Dog1 = new Greyhound()......"  inside of the main area and not part of a method.  But then I get error messages about the picture box I'm trying to reference:
"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'DayAtTheTrack.Form1.pictureBox2'"

How scope is handled in C# still confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The "fixes" you're suggesting aren't really clear, but the problem with the code you've written is that `Dog1` is a *local* variable within the `LoadDogs` method. As soon as you've finished that method, the variable has gone. (The object could potentially live on, if you do something else with it, but the *variable* is no longer relevant.)

The simplest fix to that is to make it an *instance* variable:

```
private Greyhound dog1; // Declare the field here

public void LoadDogs()
{
    // Give the field a value here
    dog1 = new Greyhound
    {
        StartingPosition = 30,
        MyPictureBox = pictureBox2, //Pointer at the picture box for this dog.
        Location = 30,  //X cordinates of the picture box
        Lane = 21 //Y cordinates of the picture box
    };
}
```

You should go back and study the part of the book which talks about different kinds of variables (local variables, instance variables and static variables). If it doesn't do a good job at explaining those things - if it's more interested in showing pretty pictures than explaining core concepts, as unfortunately many books are - then you should give up on that book and find a better one.

Comment: Ahhh, got it thank you.
Makes more sense now.  The book did dive a little bit into Local vs Instance Vs Static, but it's intermittent when I get time to study so I forgot about it.  I moved the field declaration out and now it behaves exactly as I need to.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Greyhound Dog1` is local to the `LoadDogs` function.

In your form, if you want `Dog1` to be accessible by multiple methods, it would have to be a property or field of the `Form1` class.

```
public partial Form1 
{
    private Greyhound dog1;

    public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dog1 = new Greyhound() {
            // bla bla bla, initialization
        };
    }
}
```

Also, for initialization, you might want to use `Form_Load` (if you're not using it already).